# Unable to print credentials set in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Credentials are configured in Jenkins but there's an error suggesting they are not.

I've followed documentation provided by Jenkins website.

````
  agent {
    node {
      label 'master'
    }

  }
  environment {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-key-id')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-access-key')
  }
  stages {
    stage('checkout') {
      steps {
        git(url: 'git@bitbucket.org:user/bitbucketdemo.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'jenkins')
        echo 'hello'
      }
    }
    stage('packer') {
      steps {
        echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      }
    }
  }
}```



It should print out the value of the environment variable
````

Comment: [Bitbucket] Build result notified
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63) - this is the error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

I used the Cloudbees AWS Credentials plugin. Once installed, I was able to add my AWS credentials (additional selection in Credentials pull-down menu)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0gmO.png)

Then use the following snippet in my Jenkinsfile

```
withCredentials(
                [[
                    $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                    accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                    credentialsId: 'AWS',
                    secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                ]]) {
                  sh 'packer build -var aws_access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} -var aws_secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} example4.json'
                }
```